# recursive search boolean return function

Tags: python

Write a recursive function search(l,key) that returns a boolean: True if key is in the list l; False if it isn’t. Describe the base case(s) and how the smaller problem relates to the bigger one. You may not use the in operator or the index() list method.

Can anyone explain what i need to do here for the description? I dont know anything about recurrsion to know where to start. Its for a exam review lab assignment.

Here is the code i have been provided.

```
def search(l,key):
    """
    locates key in list l.  if present, returns True; else returns False.
    PRE: l is a list.
    POST: l is unchanged; returns True if key in l; False otherwise.
    """
```

Sample Main:

```
l1 = [1, '2', 'x', 5, -2]

print search(l1, 'x')    # should output: "True"

print search(l1, 2)      # should output: "False"
```

Comment: Do me a favor and yell at your professor for using a lower-case 'l' as an identifier in his sample code.  Then read The Little Schemer :)

Comment: lol i know its confusing. LOL Anyways im still having an error come up :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All recursion tends to follow the same rules:

- Have one or more terminating cases.
- Every other case is a slightly simpler form of the current case.

So, for example, a (very inefficient) way to add two positive numbers `a` and `b`:

- if `b` is zero, return a.
- otherwise add the two numbers `a+1` and `b-1`.

Something like:

```
def addtwo (a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    return addtwo (a+1, b-1)
```

Now let's think about the cases for your assignment:

- if the list is empty, you didn't find it: return false.
- if the first element of the list is equal to your key, you found it: return true.
- otherwise look in the list made by removing the first element.

In pseudo-code (which is *very* similar to Python but different enough that you'll have to do some work):

```
def search (list, key):
    if list is empty:
        return false
    if key == first item in list:
        return true
    return search (list with first element removed, key)
```

Comment: I have a very rookie question. How would the return work if in recursion stack some return True and some return False?

Answer (score 0):

Every question regarding recursion should be dealt with the same way (usually)...Ask yourself what is the `base case` and then build on that for higher cases...

So in this question, ask yourself, when can i be certain there is no `key` in the `list`...
It's obviously when the list is empty, you're certain it's not present.

For a bigger list, you compare the first element, if it's the same as the `key`, you return `True` right away, but incase it's not, you perform all the checks for the `rest of the list`....

So studying all these aspects,
Here's your Algorithm.

```
function locate(lst,key)
    if lst == emptylist then return False
    if lst[0] == key then return True
    else return locate(lst[1..],key) //i use the notation lst[1...] to indicate list starting from 1 index.
```

Comment: for some reason, it is returning an error where the last line accepts integers and not floats. :(

Comment: @justin, could share your code, (edit your original question), and we'll try to correct it :)