# Python recursion list search

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I've worked up a simple recursive python method to search a list that can be run, but fails to return the desired result. I realise a base case (an empty list here) is needed and to build from there.
I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252471/recursive-search-boolean-return-function), which is almost identical to my question albeit a different language, but still failed to spot the problem in my own code.
My question, why does the method correctly select the base case or otherwise, but then immediately step to the recursive call again and return None.

```
def main():

    ext = ".jpg"
    accepted_list = [".jpg", ".png"]

    print(file_ext(ext, accepted_list))

def file_ext(input, list1):

    if list1 == []:
        return False
    elif input == list1[:1]:
        return True

    return file_ext(input, list1[1:])


main()
```

I expect the file_ext method to return false if an empty list occurs, or true when the search item is found in the list

Comment: Hi @allthegearbutnoidea, welcome to stackoverflow. First of all, calling your input parameter `input` overrides builtin `input` method, you should avoid practice like this.

Lets rename it to `input_extension` instead.
pythonic approach would be `if (list1) and (input_extension in list1):` would check both if list is not empty and if the extension is in list you provided. 

`listobject[:x]` returns all elements of list until  the `x`th element -> as list. So your statement is actually interpreted as`".jpg" ==[".jpg"]` which is obviously false as `str` and `list` object are not equal.

Comment: All good advice.  Thank you.  So I slipped up on type checking i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this comparison:

```
elif input == list1[:1]:
```

This compares a string with a list. Realise that slicing with `[:1]` produces a *list*, which happens to have one element (at most), but it is still a list.

Change to:

```
elif input == list1[0]:
```

This will fix it.

Note that you can replace the `if...elif...` with a single expression:

```
def file_ext(input, list1):
    return list1 and (list1[0] == input or file_ext(input, list1[1:]))
```

Comment: This was clear advice and fixed the method for me, thank you!  The one liner approach is intriguing, but I must admit i get a bit giddy trying to unwind it in my mind lol!  I'm one year into self taught CS journey, so really to need to start dabbling with these shortcuts.

Comment: My mistake was trying to use [1:] in a similar fashion to 'hd" in ML which accesses the head of a list.  I have used indexing into lists elsewhere, but this simple solution just didn't occur to me at the time.  I think a proactive step next time, would be to type check all variables within a broken program to ensure they are all in agreement